# Didn't have to needn't have done

Tags: word-choice

I have a question regarding this explanation below. Can I use "needn't have done" and "didn't have to" instead of "didn't need to"?

But we also use didn't need to to say that something was not necessary under circumstances where it was not done:

The sun came out so we didn't need to take any rainwear on the trip.

We had plenty of petrol in the tank so I didn't need to fill up.

We didn't need to wait for long for them. They arrived just after us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Needn't have done* implies that you did make a plan or take a precaution which turned out to be unnecessary.

> The weather forecast was good so we didn't need to take any rainwear.
>
> The weather was unexpectedly good so we needn't have taken our rainwear.

Comment: So "needn't have done" can't be used instead of "didn't need to" if it was done. Right? But do native speakers use "didn't have to" in that context  if it wasn't done? Instead of "needn't have done.

Comment: _Didn't have to_ and _didn't need to_ both mean 'didn't do it because it wasn't necessary'.

Comment: so not all native speakers use in different contexts and think they mean different things. For example,  didn't have to  is used to refer to obligation, didn't need to is used to talk about a necessity. I can find the examples in my book and share them if it is necessary for the context.

Comment: I can't imagine that any native speaker would 'think they mean different things' (though some people use English very strangely these days!).

Comment: I copied and pasted the explanation from the book. Perhaps I misunderstood it. Am I to understand that in 1 and 2 "didn't have to" and "didn't need to" are not interchangeable? "past obligation: had to, didn't have to
Had to / didn't have to / did you have to etc are past forms of have to and must.
Use had to
• to describe past obligation, for both must and have to.
1. Athletes who cheated in the Olympic Games had to pay for a statue of the
god Zeus.
Of course, in ancient times athletes didn't have to take drugs tests.

Comment: past necessity: needed to, didn't need to, needn't have
Use needed to (regular verb) to describe what was necessary.
He needed to stop for a drink, but he kept running.
Use didn't need to to describe what was not necessary.
In ancient Greece, winning athletes didn't need to work again.

Comment: in these examples are they interchangeable?. 1. In ancient Greece, winning athletes didn't need to work again. 2. Athletes who cheated in the Olympic Games had to pay for a statue of the god Zeus. Of course, in ancient times athletes *didn't* *have* *to* take drugs tests. – 
A

Comment: Would it be possible to say ?  In ancient Greece, winning athletes didn't have to work again. Of course, in ancient times athletes didn't need  to take drugs tests. –

Comment: Sorry - I meant that _didn't have to_ and _didn't need to_ mean the same in this particular context. _Didn't have to_ can also mean _was not obliged/made to_. The ancient Greek athletes were not made to take drugs tests. But, yes, you can say _we didn't have to take rainwear_ or _I didn't have to fill up_.

Comment: if either didn't have to or didn't need to can be used in these examples: "The sun came out so we didn't need to take any rainwear on the trip."

"We had plenty of petrol in the tank so I didn't need to fill up."

"We didn't need to wait for long for them. They arrived just after us",   can either be used in these sentences too:  "In ancient Greece, winning athletes didn't have to work again."  "Of course, in ancient times athletes didn't need to take drugs tests."

Comment: The book's examples are different: "Of course, in ancient times athletes didn't have to take drugs tests."

Comment: And here 'In ancient Greece, winning athletes didn't need to work again".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133203/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-antonia-a).